# ICO file with PNG data

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert, ico

Looking at some ICO files that have PNG data instead of ICO and I am trying to create the same. Example:

```
$ identify sample.ico 

sample.ico[0] PNG 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 884B 0.000u 0:00.000
sample.ico[1] PNG 16x16 16x16+0+0 8-bit sRGB 884B 0.000u 0:00.000

$ file sample.ico
sample.ico: MS Windows icon resource - 2 icons, 
32x32, 16 colors withPNG image data, 32 x 32, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced, 4 bits/pixel, 
16x16, 16 colors withPNG image data, 16 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced, 4 bits/pixel
```

Playing around I have found I can do something like this to get PNG ICO:

```
$ convert icon-32x32.png png8:test1.ico
$ identify test1.ico

test1.ico PNG 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 934B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

But if I use multiple input files I get multiple output files:

```
$ convert icon-16x16.png icon-32x32.png png8:test2.ico
$ ls -1 test2*

test2-0.ico
test2-1.ico
```

Not prefixing with `png8:` converts the data to ICO.

```
$ convert icon-16x16.png icon-32x32.png test3.ico
$ identify test3.ico 

test3.ico[0] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 32-bit sRGB 5.43KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test3.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 32-bit sRGB 5.43KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

If the file is too big for the ICO format, the PNG is "preserved":

```
$ convert ../icon-32x32.png ../icon-512x512.png test4.ico
$ identify test4.ico

test3.ico[0] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 32-bit sRGB 53.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
test3.ico[1] PNG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 53.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

---

How can I create a ICO file with PNG data for all sizes in ImageMagick?

Comment: ICO only goes as high as 256x256 AFAIK.

Comment: @MarkSetchell ,yes, but I do not want ICO, I want PNG ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not found any solution with imagemagick but one can use GIMP.

Just create a layer for each size and export as `file.ico`.

In options dialogue that appear check off `Compress (PNG)`.

One can also set `bpp` etc. For lower resolutions one can use for example:

- 16x16 `4bpp, 1-bit alpha, 16-slots palette`
- 24x24 `4bpp, 1-bit alpha, 16-slots palette`
- 32x32 `8bpp, 1-bit alpha, 256-slots palette`
- 48x48 `...`
- …

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do the entire conversion from SVG to ICO or SVG to PNG or PNG to ICO using ONLY Windows Direct2D APIs without needing any 3rd party tools.

I built that tool today. The ICO format has some wonky issues in that it can actually support rotation ｢by setting bmpHeader.biHeight * -1｣, and PNG ｢MSFT blog link below｣ directly but many tools don't understand it properly. So it is best to translate from SVG or PNG directly to a stricter GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA format and use

```cpp
D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F transformMatrix = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(1.0f, -1.0f); // Flip y-axis
transformMatrix._32 = static_cast<float>(renderHeight); // Reposition y-axis origin
```

To see the basics look for `DrawSvgDocument` with `ComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext5> dc;`

and

```cpp
    // Create PNG encoder
    ComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> encoder;
    hr = wicFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatPng, nullptr, &encoder);
```

Actually writing an ICO format from that is a bit more heavy lifting because you need to build the CORRECT `ICONDIR` and one or more `ICONDIRENTRY` sections for each `BITMAPINFOHEADER` entry you want to emit into your ICO file. All in all it is a bit of a one time PITA to discover the correct formats that actually work in all tools vs just some tools. It took me about 4 hours of testing and experimenting.

See also:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473

p.s., My motivation was to be able to generate SVGs directly in my scripting tool for PWAs and native apps, and then emit PNGs and ICOs at deployment time to save significantly on both file-size in a package and allow fairly infinite theming using only SVGs.